# create new structure and move elements with xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a rather badly formatted input xml that needs to be reorganized using xslt 1.0.
The hierarchy must be changed so that detail lines are divided in an upper and lower part, each containing a left and right part. I failed to create the desired output until now.
Can someone help me out, thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<document>
<Header_Label_Header_1>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>1001</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>1</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Vivida bianco strukt.</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Secret bianco 1.</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>29,5x59,5cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_1>
<Header_Label_Header_2>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>2</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Brownwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Greywood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Blackwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_2>
<Header_Label_Header_3>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>3</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>RAK Fstzg Ardesia black gl.str</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb, R9, 30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_3>
<Header_Label_Header_4>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>4</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>BAUMIT KlebeSpachtel 25kg</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2></Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_4>
<Header_Label_Header_1>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>1001</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>1</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Vivida bianco strukt.</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Secret bianco 1.</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>29,5x59,5cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_1>
<Header_Label_Header_2>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>2</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Brownwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Greywood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Blackwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_2>
<Header_Label_Header_3>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>3</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>RAK Fstzg Ardesia black gl.str</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2>frb, R9, 30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_3>
<Header_Label_Header_4>
  <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
  <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>4</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    <Detail_Line>
      <Line_Print_Description_1>BAUMIT KlebeSpachtel 25kg</Line_Print_Description_1>
      <Line_Print_Description_2></Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Header_4>
</document>
```

The output must be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<document>
<Header_Label_Upper>
    <Label_Left>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>1001</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>1</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Left>
            <Detail_Line_Left>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Vivida bianco strukt.</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Left>
            <Detail_Line_Left>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Secret bianco 1.</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>29,5x59,5cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line_Left>
    <Label_Right>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>2</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Brownwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Greywood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Blackwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
</Header_Label_Upper>
<Header_Label_Lower>
    <Label_Left>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>3</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Left>
            <Detail_Line_Left>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>RAK Fstzg Ardesia black gl.str</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb, R9, 30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Left>
    <Label_Right>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>4</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>BAUMIT KlebeSpachtel 25kg</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2></Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
</Header_Label_Lower>
<Header_Label_Upper>
    <Label_Left>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>1001</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>1</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Left>
            <Detail_Line_Left>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Vivida bianco strukt.</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Left>
            <Detail_Line_Left>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>PAR Wdfl Secret bianco 1.</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>29,5x59,5cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
    </Detail_Line_Left>
    <Label_Right>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>2</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Brownwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Greywood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
            <Detail_Line_Right>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>IRS Fstzg Porcelainw.Blackwood</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb. R9, 15x120cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line_Right>
</Header_Label_Upper>
<Header_Label_Lower>
    <Label_Left>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>3</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Left>
            <Detail_Line>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>RAK Fstzg Ardesia black gl.str</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2>frb, R9, 30x60cm</Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line>
    <Label_Right>
      <Label_Header_Header_Company>00500</Label_Header_Header_Company>
      <Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>4</Label_Header_Header_Unique_Sequence_Number>
    </Label_Right>
            <Detail_Line>
              <Line_Print_Description_1>BAUMIT KlebeSpachtel 25kg</Line_Print_Description_1>
              <Line_Print_Description_2></Line_Print_Description_2>
            </Detail_Line>
</Header_Label_Lower>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example XML, the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" standalone="no"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- The identity transform. -->
      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- Match the root node. -->
      <xsl:template match="document">
        <xsl:copy>
          <!-- Restructure each subset of four Header_Label_Header elements. -->
          <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 4 = 1]">
            <xsl:call-template name="subset">
              <xsl:with-param name="subset-nodes" select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 4]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="subset">
        <xsl:param name="subset-nodes"/>
        <!-- Select the first and third elements and give them appropriate upper/lower labels. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$subset-nodes[position() mod 2 = 1]">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
              <Header_Label_Upper>
                <!-- Select this element and the one that follows it. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 2]"/>
              </Header_Label_Upper>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <Header_Label_Lower>
                <!-- Select this element and the one that follows it. -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 2]"/>
              </Header_Label_Lower>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the Header_Label_Header elements and give them appropriate left/right labels. -->
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), 'Header_Label_Header_')]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
        <Label_Left>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(local-name(), 'Label_Header_Header_')]"/>
        </Label_Left>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail_Line" mode="Left"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Label_Right>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(local-name(), 'Label_Header_Header_')]"/>
        </Label_Right>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail_Line" mode="Right"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail_Line" mode="Left">
    <Detail_Line_Left>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Detail_Line_Left>  
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail_Line" mode="Right">
    <Detail_Line_Right>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Detail_Line_Right>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output the desired XML.

The template could probably be improved as there is a bit of duplicated code, but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks Ben for helping out!

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks again for the solution. But I did some testing with other file and in case there are more 4 sections there is a problem. Only "Header_Label_Lower sections are created. Sorry but my example was not as it  should.

Comment: @ludoaerts, I've edited my answer to make it cope with several sets of four Header_Label_Headers. Please give it a go and see if it's what you need.

Comment: Hi Ben, all is working fine. But I forgot one detail, the "Detail_Line" nodes have to be modified to "Detail_Line_Left" and "Detail_Line_Right".

Comment: @ludoaerts, I've edited it again - have another go. (By the way, in your example you haven't updated the last view "Detail Line" nodes. I assumed you meant to...)