# Conditional XML reorganization

Tags: javascript, php, python, xml, xslt

I'm looking for an efficient way to reorganize parts of an XML document that contain multiple children of a type such as 'SmallCat' or 'BigCat'.

Here are the rules:

1. Everything except for Habitat nodes should be passed through; attributes and all.
2. Habitat nodes with less than 2 instances of either BigCat or SmallCat should be passed through.

The input document looks like:

```
<Zoo>
  <Habitat HabitatID="habitat.cage.1">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <BigCat AnimalID="Tiger.1">
      <Type>Bengal</Type>
    </BigCat>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="bobcat.1">
      <Type>Bobcat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
    <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
  </Habitat>
  <Habitat HabitatID="cage.2">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="tabycat.1">
      <Type>Tabycat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
    <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
  </Habitat>
  <ConsessionStand>
    <Type>PopcornStand</Type>
  </ConsessionStand>
</Zoo>
```

The output should look like:

```
<Zoo>
  <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.1.habitat.cage.1">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <BigCat AnimalID="Tiger.1">
      <Type>Bengal</Type>
    </BigCat>
  </Habitat>

  <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.2.habitat.cage.1">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="bobcat.1">
      <Type>Bobcat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
  </Habitat>

  <Habitat HabitatID="habitat.cage.1">
    <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
    <Child>
        <HabitatID>sub_habitat.1.habitat.cage.1</HabitatID>
    </Child>
    <Child>
        <HabitatID>sub_habitat.2.habitat.cage.1</HabitatID>
    </Child>
  </Habitat>

  <Habitat HabitatID="cage.2">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="tabycat.1">
      <Type>Tabycat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
    <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
  </Habitat>
  <ConsessionStand>
    <Type>PopcornStand</Type>
  </ConsessionStand>
</Zoo>
```

The ideal solution will use XSLT but, any solution (bash, javascript, php, python, ruby, go, etc) that gets the job done is a worthy contender.

Here's an implementation that does ~90% of the work.

This solution does not reconstruct the first **Habitat** node with references to the new **sub_habitat** child nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Habitat[count(BigCat|SmallCat) &gt; 1]">
        <xsl:param name="i"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="BigCat|SmallCat">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::BigCat">
              <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.{position()}.{../@HabitatID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::SmallCat|self::BodyTemp)]"/>
              </Habitat>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::SmallCat">
              <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.{position()}.{../@HabitatID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::BigCat|self::BodyTemp)]"/>
              </Habitat>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting output is seen here.

```
<Zoo>
  <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.1.habitat.cage.1">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <BigCat AnimalID="Tiger.1">
      <Type>Bengal</Type>
    </BigCat>
  </Habitat>
  <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.2.habitat.cage.1">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="bobcat.1">
      <Type>Bobcat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
  </Habitat>
  <Habitat HabitatID="cage.2">
    <Type>Cats</Type>
    <Food>Birds</Food>
    <SmallCat AnimalID="tabycat.1">
      <Type>Tabycat</Type>
    </SmallCat>
    <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
  </Habitat>
  <ConsessionStand>
    <Type>PopcornStand</Type>
  </ConsessionStand>
</Zoo>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: @Michael.hor257k : First, can this problem be solved using XSLT? I'm not expert enough to posit a meaningful example. Second, if so, can someone provide a working example. Third, if the problem cannot be solved using XSLT, what would an optimal solution look like in some other language?

Comment: "*can this problem be solved using XSLT?*" I believe it can - but this is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Fair enough, yet, I see the same in the question and response found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955496/create-new-structure-and-move-elements-with-xslt). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Each of the rules in your prose description of the problem translates pretty directly into a template rule. For example, the rule:

> This experience contains more than 1 element (Audiovisual and
>   Gallery),  it will be reorganized as a set of 2 discrete experience
>   children

becomes something like

```
<xsl:template match="Experience[count(Audiovisual|Gallery) gt 1]">
  <xsl:for-each select="AudioVisual|Gallery">
    <Experience ExperienceID="{../@ExperienceID}.ce.{position()}"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::AudioVisual|self::Gallery)]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Experience>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Just go through all your rules and write a template rule for each one.

Comment: When the processor invokes the rule for each Experience I expect 2 side effects. The first is the creation of a new Experience node for the discrete Audiovisual or Gallery type. The second side effect is an update to the "original node such that it references the new discrete Audiovisual Experience node as a child.

Comment: I'm afraid that shows a complete misunderstanding of the XSLT processing model. Template rules don't have side-effects: they return results. The transformation as a whole constructs a result tree; a template rule can construct part of that result tree, but it can't construct two different parts. To achieve that, you probably need two different template rules matching the same elements in a different mode.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Alas, implementing a solution with that level of sophistication with XSLT is frankly the reason why I'm looking for help.

Comment: Any chance of cutting it down to something simpler, that doesn't involve wading through so much XML and so many different cases? You'll get far more responses if you can extract the essence of the problem.

Comment: Good suggestions, I've rewritten the question to somewhat less verbose. Let's see how well this new revision of the question catches on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Zoo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Habitat/BigCat | Habitat/SmallCat"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BigCat| SmallCat">
    <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.{position()}.{../@HabitatID}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::BigCat or self::SmallCat or self::BodyTemp)]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Habitat>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Habitat">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | BodyTemp"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="BigCat | SmallCat" mode="child"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BigCat| SmallCat" mode="child">
    <Child>
        <HabitatID>
            <xsl:text>sub_habitat.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@HabitatID"/>
        </HabitatID>
    </Child>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Zoo>
   <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.1.habitat.cage.1">
      <Type>Cats</Type>
      <Food>Birds</Food>
      <BigCat AnimalID="Tiger.1">
         <Type>Bengal</Type>
      </BigCat>
   </Habitat>
   <Habitat HabitatID="sub_habitat.2.habitat.cage.1">
      <Type>Cats</Type>
      <Food>Birds</Food>
      <SmallCat AnimalID="bobcat.1">
         <Type>Bobcat</Type>
      </SmallCat>
   </Habitat>
   <Habitat HabitatID="habitat.cage.1">
      <BodyTemp>endothermic</BodyTemp>
      <Child>
         <HabitatID>sub_habitat.1.habitat.cage.1</HabitatID>
      </Child>
      <Child>
         <HabitatID>sub_habitat.2.habitat.cage.1</HabitatID>
      </Child>
   </Habitat>
</Zoo>
```

Comment: That's pretty close! An instance of Habitat with only 1 type of SmallCat or BigCat should be passed through, hence the original constraint  match='Habitat[count(BigCat|SmallCat) &gt; 1]'.

Comment: @Amvoxite That's what happens when you only post an example without explaining the **rules** that need to applied. And your example doe not even have "*an instance of Habitat with only 1 type of SmallCat or BigCat.*" Anyway, I think you have enough to finish this on your own, don't you think?